# Dual Monitor Wallpapers GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, desktop-background

I just want a different wallpaper on each of my monitors. I heard it was possible with Nitrogen on GNOME 2 but I don't see the option when I installed Nitrogen for my GNOME 3. I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 for reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can install **HydraPaper** on Ubuntu 17.10 for change desktop wallpaper.

**You can install HydraPaper on Ubuntu 17.10 or later — but you’ll first need to install Flatpak and a few dependencies**:

```
sudo apt install flatpak python-pil
```

**Then add the Flathub repo (skip if you already have it set up)**

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

**You can also try to install the app using the following command, running it from the directory you downloaded the Flatpak file to**:

```
flatpak --user install ~/Downloads/hydrapaper-1.1.2.flatpak
```

Once the app is installed, you should be able to launch it from the Applications screen by searching for it by name.

Useful Link to refer-->[Set a Different Wallpaper for Each Monitor on Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/different-wallpaper-each-monitor-ubuntu-linux)